# Unique validation in Laravel depending by User ID

Tags: laravel, validation, unique, rules

In my books app, I have the following rule on store request:

```
'title' => 'unique:books,title|required|min:3|max:128,' . $this->user()->id.',user_id',
```

At this moment, with that validation rule in StoreRequest, I have the error "This title has already been added" (thats correct, but the title was added by a different user, not by the one who's trying to add it).

What I want to achieve is to have a unique rule for title, but only for this user collection. For example: 2 different users can declare the SAME book title, but the same user cannot duplicate it.

What's wrong?

Comment: This is pretty clearly a typo, this code is adding stuff onto the `max` rule instead of the `unique` rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
'title'      => 'required|string|unique:tblbooks,id,'.$request->input('title'),
```

Comment: This provides me ```SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'words. books' doesn't exist``` ... ???

Comment: change the tblbooks to the name of your table containing the title and id fields

Comment: Yes, I did. It looks like this: 
```'title'      => 'required|string|unique: books,title,user_id,'. $request->input('title'),```

Comment: try removing the title after books, see what happens.

Comment: Seems like it works with this version:
```
unique:books,user_id
```

Answer (score 3):

The [old Laravel 5 validation documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-unique) has the example:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'
```

Which still works with Laravel 8. The example checks a unique `email_address` where the `account_id == 1`;

The [current validation documentation (Laravel 8)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique) show the example that way:

```
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('account_id', 1);
})
```

---

*Search in the docu page for "Adding Additional Where Clauses".*

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
'title' => 'required|min:3|max:128|unique:books,title,user_id,'.Auth::user()->id,
```

Comment: do you have `$this->user()->id`, or you need to use `Auth::user()->id`?

Comment: ```Auth::user()->id``` is what I'm using for user id.

Answer (score 0):

```
'title' => 'unique:books,user_id|required|min:3|max:128,' . $this->user()->id,
```

Seems to do the trick! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
'title' => 'required|min:3|max:128|unique:books,title,NULL,id,user_id,'.Auth::user()->id,
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code - what have you changed and why?